# Swift 4 Error Running Code in Extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, imessage-extension

I'm trying to upgrade my iMessage App to Swift 4. This section of example code worked perfectly in Swift 3 but gives errors when trying to move to Swift 4. The code below is in a class where the file is part of the main app target as well as the iMessage app.

```
#if IN_EXTENSION
    // Do nothing since it's running in iMessage Extension
    print("In extension")
#else
    let helper = Helper()
    helper.test()

    UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems = []

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let testViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test") as UIViewController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = testViewController
#endif
```

It gives errors such as `shared is unavailable`. Which makes total sense since it's not available in iMessage Apps.

How this worked previously is in `Other Swift Flags` I added `-DIN_EXTENSION` to the iMessage app extension but not the main app.

There are a lot of similarities between my iMessage App and main app. So I want to keep my code clean and not repeat code. So this should be possible.

I'm not sure why after converting to Swift 4 all the sudden it's throwing errors.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Obviously it is diving into the `#else` even in iMessage..

Comment: @matt Just figured this out. For some reason when rebuilding it suddenly it gave me completely different errors. After fixing those this error completely went away. Seems like a bug with Xcode or something.

Comment: Very possible! Misleading errors do happen when there are other errors. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason after rebuilding my app just now this error went away and it gave me completely different errors. After solving those this error completely went away. Seems like a bug with Xcode or something.